# Using Legend() in Python to display values

Tags: python, legend, curve-fitting

I am using python to do a curve fitting on a set of data. The program returns `a*np.exp(-b*x)+c` and I wish to show the values of `a`, `b`, and `c` in the legend of the plot. If not in the legend, just anywhere else on the plot. Could someone guide me in the right direction of how I would go about doing that? Thanks!